# How to find partial occurrence of a word in a string and replace the whole word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find the partial occurrence of a word in a string and attach a `<span>` around it.

More in detail, I want to find all the occurrences of words starting with the percentage sign "%" (for example %mystring) and replace them with `<span>%mystring<span>`.

I found some similar solutions in PHP, but I'm not sure how to go about this in JavaScript.

Comment: Please show what you have *tried*, not just state you found some PHP code that you could not use in JS. Otherwise, the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
str = 'go to this %link not this %link';
replacedStr = str.replace(/\s\%(.*?)(\s|$)/g, ' <span>%$1</span>$2');
```

Comment: It works up to a point. I can add for example <span> before my string, but how to add </span> to the end of the string too?

Comment: cant understand your requirement ? pls explain with example ?

Comment: I have the following string: %somestring - somestring can be any value and I don't know it, the only fixed information is the % sign. I want to get <span>%somestring</span>

Comment: understood.. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `replace` method;

```
'This is %mystring. What is %yourstring?'.replace(/%mystring/g, '"%mystring')
// returns This is "%mystring. What is %yourstring?
```

EDIT: I updated my answer for completeness (Vegeta's answer looks like it solved your issue):

```
var mystring = '%this is my string. what is your string?'
mystring.replace(/\%(\w+)/g, '\"%$1')
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the content of mystring, I just know it starts with a % :)

Answer (score 0):

if there is no mandate to use regex :), then try

```
var text = "sadfg dfgikwer sfd dfg3 dfg4 sdfsdfb";
text = text.split( " " ).map( function(value){ if ( value.indexOf( "dfg" ) != 0 ){ return value }else { return "new" } } ).join( " " );
alert(text);
```

this replaces a word that begins with `dfg` with `new`

making this a method

```
function replaceOldWithNew( text, oldStr, newStr )
{
  return text = text.split( " " ).map( function(value){ if ( value.indexOf( oldStr ) != 0 ){ return value }else { return newStr } } ).join( " " );
}

 replaceOldWithNew( "sadfg dfgikwer sfd dfg3 dfg4 sdfsdfb", "dfg", "new" )
```

Comment: Thanks this was cool too, but Vegeta answered first :) Thanks!

Comment: @alemur no worries at all.

Answer (score 0):

please try the next code:

```
var str = "my str is %something %somethingElse";
var newStr = str.replace(/%(\S+)/g, function(match, p1) {return '<a>' + p1 + '</a>'});
```